# unable to get JSON value response

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making an API call using node js and I'm getting the below response of type string (knew this when I did `typeOf`).

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "provider": "Press"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "senses": [
                {
                    "definitions": [
                        "this is an animal"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And from this response I need to pull `this is an animal`, and I'm trying to get the data using the below code piece.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body.results[0].senses[0].definitions[0]));
```

but this is giving me an error as below

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body.results[0].senses[0].definitions[0]));
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that object is named `body`?

Comment: Parse it before you use it - `var results = body; console.log(results[0].senses[0].definitions[0]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse the content of your object, which is not yet a JSON object. You need to parse the whole "body" variable, before trying to access the content of it.

Try this:

```
body = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(body.results[0].senses[0].definitions[0]);
```

You can also do everything in only one line, though I don't recommend it since you probably want to use this variable afterwards:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).results[0].senses[0].definitions[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are treating `body` as if it were an object (you said it was a string) and then are trying to prase "this is an animal" as if it were JSON (which is isn't).

You need to pass the **string** to `JSON.parse` and then read the properties of the results of that.

```
JSON.parse(body).results[0].senses[0].definitions[0]
```

Note where the `)` is in the corrected expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually just parse the `body` as `JSON.parse(body)` and get the `result` property from it:

```js
var body = `{
    "metadata": {
        "provider": "Press"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "senses": [
                {
                    "definitions": [
                        "this is an animal"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`;
console.log(JSON.parse(body).results[0].senses[0].definitions[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the string as object, first you need to parse the `body`:

`console.log(JSON.parse(body).results[0].senses[0].definitions[0])`